# Android - Is there any way to toggle ActionBar icon with animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have a `DrawerLayout` in my app and a custom icon in the `ActionBar`. When the menu is opened, the icon is not visible. Once the menu is closed again, the icon re-appears. Right now, it just shows\disappears instantly. I would like to add fade animations to the icon. Is there any way to achieve this effect?

This code is currently used to toggle the icon:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(!drawerOpened){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chats_activity_action, menu);
    } else {
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how the icon is defined within an XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        android:title="Add a user"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_icon"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make the `MenuItem` invisible in your layout:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
    android:title="Add a user"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/plus_icon"
    android:visible="false"/> <!-- New attribute -->
```

Then modify your `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(!drawerOpened){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chats_activity_action, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter);

        // Post delayed so the view can be built,
        // otherwise findViewById(R.id.menu_filter) would be null
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1000);

                // Make item visible and start the animation
                item.setVisible(true);
                findViewById(R.id.menu_filter).startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }, 1);
    } else{
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);


        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chats_activity_action, menu);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter);
        item.setVisible(true);

        // Post delayed so the view can be built,
        // otherwise findViewById(R.id.menu_filter) would be null
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 0.0f);
                animation.setFillEnabled(true);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                animation.setDuration(1000);

                // start the animation
                findViewById(R.id.menu_filter).startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }, 1);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                item.setVisible(false);
            }
        }, 1000); // The animation is finished after 1000ms
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Basically, the item is inflated even if the drawer is open. Afterwards, the item gets faded out with an animation and set to invisible after the animation is over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im receiving an error, `cannot resolve symbol 'Handler'`. How is this possible?

Comment: You need to import the class `Handler` and the class `AlphaAnimation` using the following command at the beginning of your source code: `import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;`

Comment: It was imported, dont know what the IDE was complaining about. Anyways, its almost perfect, it fades in nicely when the menu is closed, but suddenly disappears when the menu is opened, can you direct me what should be added to make it fade out nicely too?

Comment: I am not sure if the code works (can't test) but go ahead and try. Basically, the item is inflated even if the drawer is open. Afterwards, the item gets faded out with an animation and set to invisible after the animation is over.

Comment: Works better than i could have imagined. Perfect answer.